# Generate a Approximated NURBS surface from a point cloud

Tags: c++, cloud, point, nurbs

I have to write a C++ program that, from a list of unorganized point, calculates the approximate surface on which these points lie and generate the corresponding NURBS. I've already seen OpenNurbs but there are no function for this, and libNURBS but the function included is tagged as "in research "

Can someone help me suggesting an appropriate library useful for this task?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at PCL: http://www.pointclouds.org/blog/trcs/moerwald/index.php

I would bet that you're probably only going to find experimental or research implementations.  Unless your point data is very reliably structured or from some other synthetic source, fitting it is a very difficult problem, and good solutions are not freely available.

If you have budget, I think Geomagic or Rapidform used to have APIs for integrating their algorithms into a client app.  They both got bought by 3d systems, so that might have changed.